# A File not found exception while Generating pair of keys using java keytool

Tags: java, keytool

Well during the generation of pair of keys using java key tool,i encountered with the following error....

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mykeystore (Access is denied)
```

Help Needed to resolve this error !!

Comment: and what is the command that you are using for this

Comment: where is stored your "mykeystore"? Probably is in a folder that you can't access as current user.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -genkey -alias mykey -keystore mykeystore

Comment: later it asked password for the keystore and details like name,organisation etc,. after the entry of those details i was asked to enter password for the key that i have created with the name my key in the command.there this error occured !

Comment: Imho you aren't running cmd in admin mode. Try to type "cmd" and hit Ctrl+Shift+enter, then retry with your command

Comment: [tag:Dairo]well it worked..but am unable to find the path at there my keystore has been saved !

Comment: @noah_quick: read the "Keystore Location" paragraph from oracle's keytool documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html. Sry for late reply but I haven't seen your sentence.

Answer (score 4):

I too faced the same problem.
It got solved by giving a user area as the destination for **.keystore file**
like `c:\users\<username>\filename.keystore` during the **keytool** command.

Comment: Worked for me, Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

You can run cmd as administrator and try. It worked with me